# Excel VBA - SSL issue

Tags: excel, vba, ssl

I'm trying to make connection to a clients iSeries machine that uses SSL and am receiving error 25202 - Unable to open the key file.  Either the path was specified incorrectly or the file permissions did not allow the file to be opened.  I have been working with out network team and they have verified I'm using the correct port and that the port is open for traffic.  They also verified I have access to the file.  They asked me to research providing the key manager path in my connection string, but I can't find anything about that.  I'm looking for any help from anyone who may know something about this and/or experienced it and what the resolution was.  How do I troubleshoot finding the correct key manager path?  My current connection string is as follows...

"Driver=IBM i Access ODBC Driver;System=MySystem;User ID=MyID;Password=MyPassword;SSL=1;"